# JQUERY - onChange triggers for checkbox, radio but not for select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following code snippet in a wordpress. It is supposed to autosubmit my form whenever there is a change in my checkboxes, my radios or my selects.

It does work for the checkboxes and the radios but it doesn't trigger when I change values in my select.

Am I missing something there?

```js
function autosubmitform() {
    $(
      "#form-pass input:checkbox, #form-pass input:radio, #form-pass select"
    ).change(function () {
    //Some logic...
    });
  }

  autosubmitform();
```

Comment: Can you upload your form?

Comment: I put an answer, if it is not useful comment

Answer (score 0):

Use on change like this:

```js
$('form').on('change', event => {
  console.log('form changed!')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="radio">
  <select>
    <option>option1</option>
    <option>option2</option>
    <option>option3</option>
    <option>option4</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Using .on fixed the issue. However, I thought .change was a "shortcut" for .on('change').